Scaling gRPC Server Streaming to 100K Subscribers on GKE (Java Spring Boot Reactive)
I'm building a gRPC server streaming application using Java, Spring Boot, and reactive programming that acts as a wrapper around Google Cloud Pub/Sub. The application has two methods: /publish and /subscribe. I expect a small number of publishers and a large number of subscribers (80K - 100K).
Here's how it works:

Publishers use the /publish method to send messages to a specific topic.

The MQ server publishes the message to the specified Pub/Sub topic.

The MQ server also subscribes to the same topic and receives the message.

The MQ server then streams the message to all connected subscribers.


Setup:

gRPC Server: Java with Spring Boot and reactive programming.

GKE: e2-standard-4 machine type.

OS Limits: Increased ulimit to 20000.


The Problem:
I'm using the below script to simulate a large number of subscribers locally:
#!/bin/bash

# Number of requests to execute in this instance
NUM_REQUESTS=$1
SUBSCRIBER_OFFSET=$2

# Loop to start NUM_REQUESTS grpcurl requests in the background
for i in $(seq 1 $NUM_REQUESTS); do
  subscriber_id=$((SUBSCRIBER_OFFSET + i))

  grpcurl -cert /home/client-cert.pem -key /home/client-cert-key.pem \
  -import-path /home \
  -proto contract.proto \
  -d "{\"topic_name\": \"test\", \"subscriber_id\": \"subscriber-$subscriber_id\"}" \
  mq.abc.com:443 SubscriptionService.Subscribe &

done

echo "All grpcurl connections have been started in the background."

When I try to establish more than 5,000 connections, I get the following error:
Failed to dial target host "mq.abc.com:443": context deadline exceeded

Active connections also start dropping after a while.
Troubleshooting:

Increased ulimit to 20000 to allow more open files/sockets.

Increased the connection timeout on the client side with -connect-timeout option.


Questions:

Could the context deadline exceeded error be related to network latency, request timeouts, or server overload?

Are there specific configurations for Spring Boot Reactive gRPC to handle a large number of concurrent streams efficiently?

Are there limits on concurrent connections imposed by GKE's networking or my Ingress configuration?

What strategies can I use to optimize gRPC performance for a large number of subscribers in a reactive Spring Boot application (e.g., connection pooling, flow control)?

Are there alternative solutions I should consider for this use case, given the high fan-out requirement?


Any help would be greatly appreciated!
